# Kibana : [How to exclude wildcald expressions like **** from the search result]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying for kibana search query and want to know how to exclude "mail":"*****" from my log search query .

trying this query in kibana elastic search:

```
"must_not": [
    {
        "match_phrase": {
            "full_message": "\"mail\":\"****\""
        }
    }
{
        "query": {
            "regexp": {
                "full_message": {
                    "mail": "***"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but not working.

Please let me know if any workaround for this.

Comment: Please share the full query. Also, what is the type of the full_message field? you can find it by typing GET <index_name>/_mapping/field/full_message

Comment: Hi @NetanelMalka thanks for the comment but what I m trying to achieve is to check for the wildcard character ** ,i m unable to find the wildcard character "**" in the search.
logs we have data something like this : "mail": "***"